# Graphing/Aggregating IIS Logs from Windows Azure

Tags: iis, iis-7, logging, windows, azure

I've got IIS logging etc enabled in my Azure Web Roles - so they're there in case i want to reference them, but i'd like to pull them all in to somewhere central and run stats across them to get pretty graphs/visit/hit stats etc.

I've looked at AWStats and Weblog Analyzer but it all looks like a lot of work (importing from blob storage, AWStats doesn't look flexible enough to recognise the file names, lots of hacking around with activeperl) - does anyone know an easy way that already exists to do this?

I'm purposefully looking for IIS log analysis, I already employ tools like New Relic and Google Analytics.

Best Regards,

HC